# Gauss's law, electrical flux density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

> Q. Given a 60-μC point charge located at origin, find the total electrical flux passing through the plane z = 26 cm.

I can understand what the question means, but I can't do anything.
Is it using with gauss's law? then how can I find closed S? Because the z plane is infinite.

Could you explain this Question physical-intuition?
Also solve this problem using Gauss's law please.

Comment: I234567890=1324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those questions which very much relies on the fact that the plane is infinite.   So any electric field line which starts off going towards the plane will be counted as part of the electric flux through the plane.

Any electric field line which has a z component must reach the infinite z=26 cm plane.

Comment: I can't understand...

Comment: the solution is 30μC, Why is the soultion half of the given charge?

Comment: What happens to any electric field line which has a component in the positive z direction?  It must eventually reach the z= 26 cm infinite plane.

Comment: Could you explain using equation?

Comment: You would have to set up an integral to evaluate $\int_S \vec E \cdot \hat n \;da$.  It is one of many Physics questions which some would say is a "trick" questions.